# Issue with executing SQL Procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, syntax-error, procedure

I have an issue executing below piece of code:

```
DECLARE @CUTOFFDAYS_i INT
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQL1 NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @CUTOFFDAYS_i = 750

CREATE TABLE #TMP(
EMPID INT,
EMPNAME VARCHAR(35)
)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT EMPID, EMPNAME INTO #TMP FROM EMPDB..EMPTABLE 
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, CREATEDDATE, GETDATE()) > @CUTOFFDAYS_i
AND ERRORMESSAGE = '''''

 SET @SQL1 = 'SELECT * FROM #TMP'

 EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
 EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL1
```

Even then I don't get any result upon

```
SELECT * FROM #TMP
```

Comment: Try changing `EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL(@SQL)
 EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL(@SQL1)` to                                    `EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
 EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL1`

Comment: There should **not** be any parenthesis around the `@SQL` and `@SQL1` when using `sp_executesql`

Comment: @marc_s Even then i'm not getting records on executing this statement 'SELECT * FROM #TMP'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of # is wrong. `#TMP` is a temporary table that's only availble to the connection that makes it. I think what you're looking for is `##TMP`.

But if you need such a temporary table, I would advice you to make a proper table instead as it's much easier to manage and keep track off and keeps less strain on your tempdb.

Comment: Even if I create temporary table #TMP I cannot retrieve the details from it: CREATE TABLE #TMP( EMPID INT, EMPNAME VARCHAR(35) )

Comment: Use `##` if you really want it to be a table in tempdb. But as said - I'd advice you to make a proper table for something like that (or possible rethink your solution, it seems like there are better ways)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should declare @SQL and @SQL1 as a fixed maximum length varchar not exceeded 8000 (I guess it's not the restriction for the current MS SQL version???):

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @SQL1 NVARCHAR(1000)
```

Then you shouldn't use `()` when call `SP_EXECUTESQL`

```
 EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
 EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL1
```

And the finally you should use global temp table ##TMP in `SP_EXECUTESQL` for INSERT and then SELECT [or you should declare local #Tmp table](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/909d1c7c-57ef-43b6-b09b-c18350ece4dc/cannot-create-local-temp-table-using-spexecutesql?forum=transactsql) before the first `SP_EXECUTESQL` call

```
DECLARE @CUTOFFDAYS_i INT
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @SQL1 NVARCHAR(1000)

SET @CUTOFFDAYS_i = 750

SET @SQL = 'SELECT EMPID, EMPNAME INTO ##TMP FROM EMPDB..EMPTABLE 
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, CREATEDDATE, GETDATE()) > @CUTOFFDAYS_i
AND ERRORMESSAGE = '''''

 SET @SQL1 = 'SELECT * FROM ##TMP'

 EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
 EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL1
```

Comment: Even if I create temporary table #TMP I cannot retrieve the details from it:

CREATE TABLE #TMP(
 EMPID INT,
 EMPNAME VARCHAR(35)
 )